# update nth document in a nested array document in mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I need to update a document in an array inside another document in Mongo DB.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51cff693d342704b5047e6d8"),
        "author" : "test",
        "body" : "sdfkj dsfhk asdfjad ",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "author" : "test",
                        "body" : "sdfkjdj\r\nasdjgkfdfj",
                        "email" : "test@tes.com"
                },
                {
                        "author" : "hola",
                        "body" : "sdfl\r\nhola \r\nwork here"
                }
        ],
        "date" : ISODate("2013-06-30T09:12:51.629Z"),
        "permalink" : "mxwnnnqafl",
        "tags" : [
                "ab"
        ],
        "title" : "cd"
}
```

If I try to update first document in comments array by below command, it works.

```
db.posts.update({'permalink':"cxzdzjkztkqraoqlgcru"},{'$inc': {"comments.0.num_likes": 1}})
```

But if I put the same in python code like below, I am getting Write error, that it can't traverse the element. I am not understanding what is missing!!
Can anyone help me out please.

```
    post = self.posts.find_one({'permalink': permalink})       
    response = self.posts.update({'permalink': permalink},
                                 {'$inc':"comments.comment_ordinal.num_likes": 1}})

WriteError: cannot use the part (comments of comments.comment_ordinal.num_likes) to traverse the element
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*comment_ordinal* should be a substitution, not the index itself. You're treating it like an integer that can be mapped to an ordinal number. I mean you should do something like:

```
updated_field = "comments." + str(comment_ordinal) + ".num_likes"

response = self.posts.update({'permalink': permalink}, {'$inc': {updated_field: 1}})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed it that it is integer and should be changed.

Comment: string concatenation using `+` is not recommended see [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @user3100115 Please be more descriptive when making a suggestion instead of sharing the whole pep8 rules :) I agree that most of the cases using format is the safest choice but I don't see a problem using "+" for string concatenation if you know what you're doing. Especially if you're writing a short script as I believe this is such an example.

Comment: No specific link. Search "string concatenation" in that page.:).

Comment: @user3100115 I didn't ask for a link and I already know about suggestions. I suggested you to support your claim with your ideas and explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong you need to build your query dynamically and the best way to do that is using the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method.

```
response = self.posts.update_one(
    {'permalink': permalink},
    {'$inc': {"comments.{}.num_likes".format(comment_ordinal): 1}}
)
```

Also you should consider to use the [`update_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method for single update and [`update_many`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) if you need to update multiple documents because [`update`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) is deprecated.